# ¿Cómo se usa la estructura if else en MySQL Worckbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Soy nuevo utilizando MySQL y no se como usar correctamente la estructura if else, se usar bien el if pero estoy teniendo problemas para poder usarlo con el else. Algún ejemplo de la estructura sería de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola JaArques_Player te dejo un ejemplo seria esto:

```
CASE WHEN e.Nombre IS NULL THEN '' ELSE e.Nombre END as Nombre
```

Seria lo correspondiente a:

```
if(e.nombre == null){ 
   '' 
}else{
  e.nombre
}
```